# Program to check similar elements of two array

Tags: c++

I m writing a program to get the common numbers from 2 arrays......but whenever i run this program..i get the 2nd element of the 1st array as a common number...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int numbChecker(int arr1[], int arr1Digit, int arr2[], int arr2Digit) {

    int arrDigit = arr1Digit*arr2Digit, arr1indx = 0, arr2indx = 0 , counter = 0;
    while(arrDigit != 0) {
        if (arr1[arr1indx] == arr2[arr2indx]) {
            cout << arr1[arr1indx] << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "no" << endl;
        }
        arrDigit--;
        counter++;
        arr2indx++;

        if (counter == (arr2Digit - 1)) {
            arr1indx++;
            arr2indx = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    int a[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    int b[5] = {5,6,7,8,9};
    numbChecker(a,4,b,5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it using a debugger?

Comment: Don't just dump your broken code on us without any explanation of what it is supposed to do, and what the expected output of the program is.

Comment: if you are allowed to use, you can use `set` and `intersection` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the numbers that occur in both arrays all you have to do is to compare every value of the first array against every value of the second array which can be done using two nested `for`-loops:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

void numbChecker(int arr1[], std::size_t arr1Digit, int arr2[], std::size_t arr2Digit)
{
    for (std::size_t i{}; i < arr1Digit; ++i)
        for (std::size_t k{}; k < arr2Digit; ++k)
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[k])
                std::cout << arr1[i] << '\n';
}
```

this code will report some entries multiple times if they occur multiple times in one of the arrays, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised how you program did not give array out of bounds exception at the following line:

```
if (counter == (arr2Digit - 1))
```

Since you are keeping on incrementing counter variable and not resetting it anywhere, After the first iteration of arr1 i.e. when arr1index=1 , counter will be equal to 5, arr1index =1 and arr2index=0. After 4 iteration of arr2index, i.e. when arr2index=5, program will see that counter = 9 arr2index =5, so if condition will return false and in next iteration arr2 will be accessed with index=5 resulting in array out of bound exception

Comment: "I am surprised how you program did not give array out of bounds exception [...] and in next iteration arr2 will be accessed with index=5 resulting in array out of bound exception" There is no such thing as an "array out of bounds exception" in C++.